# package import issue java

Tags: java, import

I am going crazy with this issue, i know its something small and i can't figure it out. I am using terminal, in the root directory i have all the files including two folders that contain other java files. I am trying to include a class file from one of this folders but it keeps giving me an error that the package does not exist. my import statement is as follows, import x1.x2.*; where x1 is the name of the folder and the x2 is the name of the java file. The file where i am importing is located at say etc/y and the folder is located at etc/y/x1.  The error is that the folder does not exist.

Comment: Please provide your exact statements and folder layout. In general: Package names must match the folder structure, you cannot simply place java classes anywhere you want.

Answer (score -1):

> my import statement is as follows, import x1.x2.*; where x1 is the name of the folder and the x2 is the name of the java file.

you don't import java files, but java classes (which are equivalent to the filenames but without the file name extension.)
So the correct import would be

```
import x1.x2;
```

Comment: i meant java classes, even with that, it still doesn't work

Comment: in this case I need the actual error message of the java compiler and your real project directory layout.

Comment: this is how i am compiling, "javac -cp /../protobuf.jar *.java" by the way the folders are compiled already, no issues. Then i get the following error "AP.java:1: error: package AirportData.AirportDataProto does not exist
import AirportData.AirportDataProto.*;" with the arrow pointing at the import.

Comment: all the files including the two folders are in the directory "/../Desktop/jr" thats the root directory, the two other folders are in "/../Desktop/jr/PlaceData" and /../Desktop/jr/AirportData"

Comment: I forgot to include the * in the above comment about compiling before .java but its there.

Comment: does the folder `Desktop/jr/AirportData/AirportDataProto` exist?

Comment: so its actually `Desktop/jr/AirportData/AirportDataProto.java`?
and your import is `AirportData.AirportDataProto.;` with an dot before the semicolon?

Comment: its both .java and .class and the import is AirportData.AirportDataProto.*;

Comment: then, as I suggested in the answer, remove the dot and the star: 
`import AirportData.AirportDataProto;`

Comment: yes, i have tried that, but still no luck, same issue persists.

Comment: are you on a linux system?

Comment: Perfect! Please execute following commands and add the result to your question so that it gets formatted nicely: `find . | sed 's/^\./    ./'` and `find . -name *.java -exec grep -l import | sed 's/^\./    ./'`. make sure to have 4 spaces beween `/    .`

Comment: it says "find: AirportServer.java: unknown primary or operator"

Comment: ok, that means you working directory is `Desktop/jr/AirportData/` where the file `AirportServer.java` is located, right? what ar the top 5 lines in `AirportServer.java`?

Comment: no the AirportServer.java is not in the AirportData directory, its in the root directory

Comment: AirportData and PlaceData folders are auto generated by the google protocol buffers

Comment: .
 ./.DS_Store
 ./AirportData
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$1.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$Airport$1.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$Airport$Builder.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$Airport.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$AirportList$1.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$AirportList$Builder.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$AirportList.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$AirportListOrBuilder.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto$AirportOrBuilder.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto.class
 ./AirportData/AirportDataProto.java

Comment: ./AirportData/protobuf.jar
 ./airportdata.proto
 ./airports-proto-original.bin
 ./airports-proto.bin
 ./Airports.java
 ./AirportServer.class
 ./AirportServer.java
 ./AirportsInterface.java
 ./AP.class
 ./AP.java
 ./CLArgs.java
 ./Client.java
 ./PlaceData
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$1.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$Place$1.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$Place$Builder.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$Place.class

Comment: ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$PlaceList$1.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$PlaceList$Builder.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$PlaceList.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$PlaceListOrBuilder.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto$PlaceOrBuilder.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto.class
 ./PlaceData/PlaceDataProto.java
 ./PlaceData/protobuf.jar
 ./placedata.proto
 ./places-proto-original.bin
 ./places-proto.bin
 ./Places.java
 ./PlaceServer.java
 ./PlacesInterface.java
 ./policy
 ./protobuf.jar
 ./README.md
 ./RemoteResult.java

Comment: didn't I asked you to put it in the question?

Comment: are we looking ate the imports in AP.java?

Comment: _it still doesn't format correctly_ it needs 4 spaces before each line

Comment: imports at AP.java are done same way as others, and no i mean i added the 4 spaces but when i try to copy the results in here the stack overflow it doesn't format it correctly

Comment: in which file did you make the change in the import?

Comment: all of them I made changes to

Comment: ok, it's rather late at my location. I might check back tomorrow. maybe someone else can help meanwhile...